# VBA SQL Difficulties with comparison of Dates with different formats

Tags: sql, vba, date, comparison

With Visual Basic for Applications, I want to select all tuples from an access-table with a specific date. The dates are formatted as "DD.MM.YYYY" but due to SQL, I have to compare dates as "YYYY.MM.DD".

So, I've written the following code to do this:

```
CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM TabAusw WHERE Datum = " & Format(Spektren("Spektren.Datum"), "YYYY-MM-DD"), dbOpenDynaset)
```

Spektren("Spektren.Datum") and the field "Datum" in "TabAusw" are the dates I want to compare, both are stored as dbDate.

But executing the line shown above wont give me the desired results. The SQL-code seems to be right, but I won't get the tuple because I compare two dates of different format. At least thats my idea of whats the problem here.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: try `"SELECT * FROM TabAusw WHERE Datum = #" & Spektren("Spektren.Datum") & "#"`

Comment: You were right with adding the two hashs, but I need the function Format anyway: `"SELECT * FROM TabAusw WHERE Datum =#" & Format(Spektren("Spektren.Datum"), "YYYY-MM-DD") & "#"`

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is get the dateparts as integers and use this for comparison. saves you the trouble of different locales.

Comment: And gives me the trouble of having to manage several additional variables. The actual solution was as easy as can be, just adding two hashs did the trick.